# How can I fill in values in pandas merge when merged rows don't match

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, merge

I have two dataframes with a common `"License Number"` column. I want to merge them with `indicator` so I can later pick `left_only` or `right_only` to find entries that only appear in one of the dataframes.

However, I find that when merging, everything goes fine as long as the entries are the same in A and B, so theoretically, this would work perfectly for dataframes of the same size where all the entries are equal.

If there is an entry in A, but not in B, the merge will still pull row data from B and put it besides the data from A, even though the key used to merge (`License Number`) don't match between those rows.

Here is how I do it ([code you can run with sample data is here](https://repl.it/JPuH/0)):

```
merged_sheet = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='License Number', left_index=True, right_index=True, how='outer', indicator=True)
```

In the example with data that I attach, the three first rows are fine, but when it arrives to the fourth row, there is no match between both dataframes, but instead of labeling it as `NaN` or whatever (what Excel would tag as #N/A in a VLOOKUP) it just simply pulls information from a totally unrelated row.

My expected result is that when the `License Number` column don't match, the merge just leaves either a blank space or some error message, but not that it moves all the data one row up.

Comment: You shouldn't join on indexes in this problem.  Remove left_index=True and right_index=True.  Just join on 'License Number'.  I think that will provide you with your expected results.

Comment: Thanks, that was right. I got confused with the meaning of joining by index and now I see that it doesn't apply here.

Comment: Not at all, after all you suggested the right solution. Submit and I will accept.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this particular case, you shouldn't join on indexes, remove `left_index = True` and `right_index = True`.

```
merged_sheet = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='License Number', how='outer', indicator=True)
```

Then you can see all non-matching rows in the `outer` join with the following statement:

```
merged_sheet.query('_merge != "both"')
```